# How can I recover missing iCloud storage space?

Tags: icloud, backup

I have an iCloud account with the free 5GB storage, which I want to use for backups.

I have a strange situation where my iCloud is showing as having only 2.2GB space available:

[image]

[image]

But isn't showing what is using up the space.

I have previously used it for backups of various devices, but these aren't showing.

How can I recover my lost space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up phoning up iCloud support, and they were similarly baffled. They tried a load of things (none of which worked), and eventually they then asked me to delete the WhatsApp Documents & Data storage. Despite it saying that only 350MB was being used by WhatsApp, deleting this immediately freed up around 2.8GB (350MB plus the ~2.5GB of "lost" space) in iCloud.

Answer (score -1):

**[Manage your iCloud storage](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204247)**

Learn how to manage your iCloud storage if you reach or exceed your storage limit.

You can manage your storage by [upgrading your iCloud storage plan](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4874) or reducing the amount of storage that you're using. You can reduce your iCloud storage by choosing which apps and backups to store, and you can move or delete documents, photos, and email messages that you no longer need.*
Use these steps to see how much iCloud storage is available in your account:

**On your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch:**

1. If you're using iOS 8 or later, tap Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage.
2. If you're using an earlier version of iOS, tap Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup.
3. On your Mac, go to Apple menu > System Preferences, click iCloud, then click Manage.
4. On your PC, open [iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12803?locale=en_US), then click Manage.

**Before you delete anything, you might want to [archive or make copies of your iCloud data](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204055).**

Comment: As you can see, the OP has already done this, and he is using **2.2 GB**, where it should only be around **350 MB**